# Cycle that represents Scrum and UX work together

Tags: scrum, user-experience-design

[PSU](https://www.scrum.org/professional-scrum-user-experience-certification) assessment query:

What is the best cycle representing Scrum and UX work together, out of following, according to Scrum?

1. Build then Measure then Learn
2. Plan then Do then Check then Review
3. Discovery then Sprint Delivery then Sprint
4. Sprint Planning then Design then Development then Test then Sprint Review

I think, **option 1**, can be best answer but not sure as can't find any evidence on Scrum.org.

Comment: I confess to be quite unsure as to how "UX = User Experience Design" has anything to do with, or any possible *conflict* with, "project management." ("Scrum" or otherwise ...)

Comment: Assessment tests are only as good as the test designers, and it's not always possible to know what they have in mind as the "correct" answer. In formal Scrum, UX is never a separate activity, so trying to make it separate or sequential is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is 2.

For both Scrum and UX you do the following steps:

1. Design pattern or Plan
2. Implement design or DO
3. A/B test, test
4. Improve

Answer (score 1):

### Scrum is founded on empirical process control theory, or empiricism

[Scrum is founded on empirical process control theory, or empiricism.](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html)

Here [is a detailed justification of the above by Ken Schwaber](https://www.scruminc.com/agile-processes-ken-schwabers-letter/), who jointly developed the Scrum framework with Jeff Sutherland.

The Three Pillars of Empiricism are:

- Transparency: Significant aspects of the process must be visible to those responsible for the outcome
- Inspection: Scrum users must frequently inspect Scrum artifacts and progress toward a Sprint Goal to detect undesirable variances
- Adaptation: If an inspector determines that one or more aspects of a process deviate outside acceptable limits, and that the resulting product will be unacceptable, the process or the material being processed must be adjusted

I am not that familiar with the UX cycle. Based on the above, you can try and figure out which option fits best.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Build then Measure then Learn" - It sounds to me like **Lean**. Not Scrum and UX.
2. "Plan then Do then Check then Review" - Is it not **PDCA** with a tweak?
   The 'act' is replaced with 'review' to give it a scrumish feeling, but it is not Scrum and not UX.
3. "Discovery then Sprint Delivery then Sprint" - Whatever it is, has nothing to do neither with Scrum nor with UX.
4. "Sprint Planning then Design then Development then Test then Sprint Review" - This one combines Scrum events with a cross-functional delivery process which includes UX.